# querying a collection with a value greater than 0 while keeping the current month whether the value is 0 or greater than 0

Tags: c#, linq

I have this scenario where I need to select the `Bar` Object with `Val` greater than 0 while keeping the Object with the current month whether `Val` is 0 or greater than 0.

```
var currentMonth = new DateTime(2015, 3, 1); // Just an example
var foo = new List<Bar>()
{
  new Bar { Date = '01/01/2015', Val = 40 },
  new Bar { Date = '02/01/2025', Val = 30 },
  new Bar { Date = '03/01/2015', Val = 0 },
  new Bar { Date = '04/01/2015', Val = 2 },
  new Bar { Date = '05/01/2015', Val = 5 }
}

// I also need to select the current month whether it's Val is 0 or greater than 0
// Stuck here
var fooResult = foo.Where(f => f.Val > 0);
```

So the result should be something like this:

```
{
  new Bar = { Date = '03/01/2015', Val = 0 },
  new Bar = { Date = '04/01/2015', Val = 2 },
  new Bar = { Date = '05/01/2015', Val = 5 }
}
```

Or if currentMonth is declared as this. `var currentMonth = new DateTime(2015, 4, 1);`

The result should be something like this:

```
{
  new Bar { Date = '04/01/2015', Val = 2 },
  new Bar { Date = '05/01/2015', Val = 5 }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Declare `Date` as `DateTime` not `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var fooResult = foo.Where(f => f.Val > 0 || currentMonth.Month ==Convert.ToDateTime(f.Date).Month);
```